# Append rows of same data and Transpose it into columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have created a dataframe from an excel sheet using pandas. The issue with this data frame is the data structure provided to me. The data structure is somewhat complex where the same data types were given in rows structure. So I had to use df.transpose() to first transpose the data, but the issue occurs after transposing the data. so I am getting the data in multiple split sections and I need to append the transposed data in single columns.
[Before Transpose of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QixfA.png)

[Data after Transposing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvBkl.png)

[Needed output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDAX7.png)

Update fixed the issue:
Attaching the below code for reference.

df_in = pd.read_csv('sample_copy2.csv',index_col=['Year'])
df_t =df_in.transpose(copy=True)
print(df_t)

df = df_t
s = df.columns.to_series()

df.columns = [df.columns, s.groupby(s).cumcount()]
dft = df.stack().sort_index(level=1).fillna(0).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
df_f=dft.set_index('index')

print(df_f)

Answer (score 0):

since you haven't provided any reproducible code, we wouldn't be able to provide any solution as a code. However, I can answer at high level.

The transpose that you have done is absolutely right. Why don't you make a new data frame with the repeated data from columns E, F, G, H and then concat the two data frame. For concat in pandas go to this link: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Hope this is helpful.